# eclipse loading src folder weirdly

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using git with fellow student, now I've noticed that if I load a branch of another student it imports the src folder weirdly.

[image]

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse is not recognizing your src directory as a source folder, and therefore not displaying the underlying directories as packages.

You need to define the source folders in your project, typically `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` (Maven convention).

If someone else's branch uses different source folders than you, then you get this problem when you switch. It might be useful to either follow the same project structure if you work together, or use separate Eclipse projects.

Comment: Aside from this, your project should have a file called `.classpath` where the location of the source folder is defined. You can open the Navigator (deprecated) view and the file should be located in the (root) project folder. In there, there should be a `<classpathentry kind="src">` node. The `path` attribute points to the location of the source file. It is also possible that one of you overwrote this path and broke the project. I recommend you fix this entry (if this is the issue) and add the .classpath file to your .gitignore to avoid overwriting this file.

Comment: As Adriaan pointed out, if your project is a Maven project, both `main/java` and `test/java` must be defined in the .classpath file as source locations.